# Como abrir outra tela em Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Tenho um app para scanner QRCODE e tenho a seguinte verificação:

```dart
// Executa função para o scanner
Future _scan() async {
  String barcode = await scanner.scan();
  if (barcode.contains("cx-")) {
  // this._outputController.text = barcode;
    onPressed: (){
      Navigator.push(
        context, 
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => ScanCx()
        ),
      );
    };
  }else {
    print("Código não encontrado!");
  }
}
```

Porém, quando cai no if contém cx, chega no `onPress` ele não está fazendo a navegação para a tela de `ScanCx`.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma dica, caso sua aplicação comece a crescer para não ter que digitar essa linha “enorme” e para ficar mais organizado, você pode criar rotas.

Para isso, basta inserir as rotas para as telas no build do main.dart como no exemplo abaixo:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    title: 'Teste',
    routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/homepage' : (BuildContext context) => new HomePage(),
    },
 );}
```

Em seguida basta usar a linha abaixo para poder chamar a tela desejada.

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/homepage');
```

Bons estudos!

Answer (score 2):

Olá! Ao que me parece, o que está sobrando no seu código é justamente o **OnPressed**.
Como está chamando em uma função _scan, deve apenas executar a função Navigator.push( ... ).  Pois, o onPressed é um evento, normalmente usado para vincular a um widget, associado a ação de apertar do usuário.

Com a mudança o código deve ficar +/- assim:

```
// Executa função para o scanner
Future _scan() async {

String barcode = await scanner.scan();
if (barcode.contains("cx-")) { 
    Navigator.push(
      context, 
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => ScanCx()
      ),
    ); 
} else {
  print("Código não encontrado!");
}

}
```